# MS Access VBA/SQL: Import CSV and Compare to Existing Records

Tags: database, vba, csv, ms-access

I need to import sales data from an external source into an Access database. The system that generates the sales reports allows me to export data within a specified date range, but that data may change due to updates, late reported data, etc. I want to loop through each line of the CSV and see if that row already exists. If it does, ignore it; if it doesn't add a new record to the sales table.

Unless I'm misunderstanding it, I don't believe I can use DoCmd.TransferText as the data structure does not match the table I'm importing it to - I am only looking at importing several of the columns in the file.

What is my best option (1) access the data within my file to loop through, and (2) to compare the contents of a given row against a given table to see if it already exists?

Comment: create an append query against the linked csv file that will append new records based on a LEFT join

Answer (score 1):

Consider directly querying the csv file with Access SQL, selecting needed columns and run either of the [`NOT IN` / `NOT EXISTS` / `LEFT JOIN ... NULL`](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/) queries to avoid duplicates.

```sql
INSERT INTO [myTable] (Col1, Col2, Col3)
SELECT t.Col1, t.Col2, t.Col3
FROM [text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited(,);Database=C:\Path\To\Folder].myFile.csv  t
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1 FROM [myTable] m
   WHERE t.Col1 = m.Col1);       -- ADD COMPARISON FIELD(S) IN WHERE CLAUSE
```

Comment: *Be sure to remove comment in code as Access queries disallow it*